# Detecting a folded line or an incremental search (?)

Tags: vim

Okey, I agree - the title is useless. The thing is, I have no idea how to put this into a one liner...

What I'm trying to do is to map the space key so that it serves as a *:nohl* mapping, but at the same time, when it is on a folded line, to serve as a `za` in normal mode (open/close fold).

*Is this even possible?*

What I'm having trouble is distinguishing between the two - is there a way to "detect" a folded line below the cursor, or to detect an incremental search "currently in progress" (as in, there is something highlighted)?

Or am I tackling this in a completely wrong way? All advices welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reusing ideas from [Andy Rk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9272785/11621):

```
function! FoldSetWithNoHL()
    set nohls
    if (foldclosed(line('.')) >= 0)
        exe "normal za"
    endif
endfunction

map <space> :silent! call FoldSetWithNoHL()<cr>
```

Comment: This has the unfortunate side effect of turning off search highlighting completely instead of just clearing the current search highlighting. It also opens folds but does not close them.

Answer (score 2):

It may be ugly, but it worked for me:

```
noremap <Space> :nohl<CR> za
```

The drawback is an error occuring when pressing space on unfolded lines.

Answer (score 1):

Incorporating fixes to the issues I listed in my earlier comment:

```
function! ToggleFoldWithNoHL()
  if foldlevel('.')
    normal! za
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <space> :nohlsearch<cr>:call ToggleFoldWithNoHL()<cr>
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to detect that there's an active search highlight, so if you have a search active inside a fold, this will clear the search but also close the fold. In that case, another space should put you right back where you want to be.

Comment: Note that you don't need `execute` there. `normal za` by itself (without quotes) works, although you might want to use `normal! za` in case either `z` or `za` are remapped to something else.

Comment: Thanks. I meant to include the `!`, but am still learning the wheres and whens of `execute` and such. Editing to incorporate.