# Is it possible to jump to the next closed fold in Vim?

Tags: vim, code-folding

In Vim, I often find myself wanting to do a quick <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to jump to the previous or next fold in a file. The problem is, I frequently want to *skip* all the open folds, and just jump to the nearest closed fold.

Is there a way to do this? I see no built-in keymap in the help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let me propose the following implementation of the described behavior.

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zj :call NextClosedFold('j')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zk :call NextClosedFold('k')<cr>

function! NextClosedFold(dir)
    let cmd = 'norm!z'..a:dir
    let view = winsaveview()
    let [l0, l, open] = [0, view.lnum, 1]
    while l != l0 && open
        exe cmd
        let [l0, l] = [l, line('.')]
        let open = foldclosed(l) < 0
    endwhile
    if open
        call winrestview(view)
    endif
endfunction
```

If it is desirable for the mappings to accept a count for the number
of repetitions of the corresponding movement, one can implement
a simple function for repeating any given command:

```
function! RepeatCmd(cmd) range abort
    let n = v:count < 1 ? 1 : v:count
    while n > 0
        exe a:cmd
        let n -= 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

and then redefine the above mappings as follows:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zj :<c-u>call RepeatCmd('call NextClosedFold("j")')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zk :<c-u>call RepeatCmd('call NextClosedFold("k")')<cr>
```

Comment: @David:  Thanks!  I have made a refactoring on the code to simplify the jumping loop and to keep the cursor in place if there is no closed fold in desired direction.  (The latter behavior conforms to that of `zj`/`zk` commands when no fold can be found below/above.)

Comment: @ib. could you please provide the changed script?

Comment: @Glenn: If you refer to the refactoring I mentioned in my comment, the code in the answer has been already updated to include it.

Comment: Is there any way to adapt this function to allow a count, such as `[count]<leader>zj`?

Comment: @travisw: There is. I have updated the answer to show one way to support the count for repetitions in the proposed mappings.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, as far as I know, a build-in method to do that. Interesting idea, though.

If I had some time at the moment, I might try to figure out a way to do it — unfortunately, being busy nowadays, all I can suggest you is to look at the *[Detecting a folded line or an incremental search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271148/detecting-a-folded-line-or-an-incremental-search/9273570#9273570)* question (particularly the `foldclosed` function) and try to make a function yourself. Checking every line, if fold is open, skip… something along those lines.