# Vim folding - Close all children recursively under cursor

Tags: vim, folding

I know how to open all folds under cursor with `zO`.

But how to do reverse?

I want something like `za` does, but also with recursivity.

PS. I know there is `zC`, but it closes all parent folds in relation to current line and I want to close children.

Answer (score 6):

1. Close the parent fold
2. Select closed fold and next line
3. `:foldc!` - closes all folds in range `` `<,`> `` (read `:h foldc`)

You can obviously map that sequence.

Comment: If you substitute step 3 by simple typing zC it also does the trick, doesn't it?

Comment: It actually folds child folds, but it also folds parent ones, doesn't it?

Comment: I rolled my eyes when you mentioned `:foldclose`, but to my surprise `:%foldc!` actually works. That is certainly worthy of an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

I did not actually find an exact answer to this question, but a few commands than could be a workaround in some cases are:

- `zM`: Closes recursively the root folds and all their children
- `zm`: Increases the foldlevel by one, i.e. closes the innermost level of folds that are not yet folded

The opposite commands are:

- `zR`: All folds are open
- `zr`: Decreases the foldlevel by one

Comment: `zM` is for closing all folds, not doing what you describe here, it is what `zC` does.

Comment: @jdhao, `zC` closes all folds **under the cursor** recursively. `zM` closes **all** folds, but I wanted to remark that children's folds are closed recursively as well, not just the root level.

Answer (score 4):

Note: the question deals with **only current children**. I.e to close/open till current fold level, and NOT all the way as `zC`, `zO`, `zA`, `zM`, `zR`.

### Fold only current children recursive

> zx  folds: Undo manually opened and closed folds: re-apply
> 'foldlevel', then do "zv": View cursor line.
> Also forces recomputing folds.  This is useful when using
> 'foldexpr' and the buffer is changed in a way that results in
> folds not to be updated properly.
>
> zc  close folded text

I think you want to combine both:

1. go to a line in father folding level
2. Press (in normal mode) `zxzc`. Or remap it: `nnoremap zxc zxzc`

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

### Unfold only current children recursive

Btw:
to do the opposite, open recursive all children: `zczA`

Credits: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16046/29452

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

### Un-/Fold only selected recursive

Or to open/close a **desired range** of folds recursive:

1. Select the range visually.
2. :foldo (as previous [link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16046/29452)) or :foldc (as @majkinetor [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633870/vim-folding-close-all-children-recursively-under-cursor/21634546#21634546)).

Tips to select the range visually:

```
]z jump to end of current open fold.
[z jump to beginning of current open fold.
zj moves the cursor to the next fold.
zk moves the cursor to the previous fold.
```

To jump through closed folds in Vim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407015/9391770 (I did not test it yet)

Answer (score 0):

I had this need for a long time too, and what I found out as the closest solution was using `zM` to close all folds recursively and then `zv` to reopen the line at cursor previous position (before closing folds). Maybe it helps.

Regards.