# vim remap fold navigation using leader key

Tags: vim

I picked up [this handy function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407015/395059) for skipping up and down closed folds in vim:

```
let mapleader = ","
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zj :call NextClosedFold('j')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zk :call NextClosedFold('k')<cr>
function! NextClosedFold(dir)
    let cmd = 'norm!z' . a:dir
    let view = winsaveview()
    let [l0, l, open] = [0, view.lnum, 1]
    while l != l0 && open
        exe cmd
        let [l0, l] = [l, line('.')]
        let open = foldclosed(l) < 0
    endwhile
    if open
        call winrestview(view)
    endif
endfunction
```

As you can see, my `leader` key is set to `,`.

So now if I issue the command `,zj` my cursor is moved to the next closed fold. However, what I want is to have the `zj` command defaulted to moving to the next closed fold, and I want `,zj` to move to the next fold (open or closed).

What is the most elegant way to write the remapping so my vim behaves the way I want it to?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want this.

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zj zj
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zk zk
nnoremap <silent> zj :call NextClosedFold('j')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> zk :call NextClosedFold('k')<cr>
function! NextClosedFold(dir)
    let cmd = 'norm!z' . a:dir
    let view = winsaveview()
    let [l0, l, open] = [0, view.lnum, 1]
    while l != l0 && open
        exe cmd
        let [l0, l] = [l, line('.')]
        let open = foldclosed(l) < 0
    endwhile
    if open
        call winrestview(view)
    endif
endfunction
```

`nnoremap` makes mapping non recursive so even if you redefine what `zj` and `zk` do you can always get back their default behavior. Then we just map `zj` and `zk` to the behavior you want.