# VIM: How could I create a keymapping from this eval?

Tags: vim

For example, another ternary operator with map k:

```
nnoremap <expr> k (v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k')
nnoremap <expr> j (v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j')
```

When you go line down on a wrapped line, gk makes that you go to the next fictional line of a wrapped line. But when you do 5j, it will go 'over' the wrapped line. It worked fine.

In my case, I have mapped the zj to NextClosedFold() function.

But I thought it would be better, if I'm currently in a opened fold, and with zj, I could to the end of a opened fold, like ]z.

So I decided to create a map:

```
nnoremap <silent> sj (foldclosed('.') == -1 ? ]s : au call NextClosedFold('j')<cr>)
```

The `:echo foldclosed('.')` will indicate if you're on a folded line or not. If youre not on a closed fold (-1), it will give ]s, but when this is not the case, it will move to the next closed fold. But the map is not working. I think it has something to do with the closing parenthesis, that Vim will interpret as closing the evaluation too early.

Any thoughts how to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nnoremap <expr> sj foldclosed('.') == -1? ']s':NextClosedFold('j')
```

Note:

- I think `NextClosedFold()` is your own function, also I have no idea what does the `j` argument mean, I just use it in the mapping. Your function should return a string, indicating the keystrokes in that case.
- You should use `<expr>` mapping
- You should not use `call Func()<cr>` in a `<expr>` mapping, the `au` doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For reference, I have NextClosedFold picked [from this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403098/is-it-possible-to-jump-to-closed-folds-in-vim). I tried your suggestions, which didn't worked. Then I tried this: " nmap 1sj :call NextClosedFold('j')<cr>
" nmap 2sj ]z
" nmap <expr>  foldclosed('.') == -1 ? '2sj' : '1sj'  Any ideas?